# Is there a similar R function for "%perp" from RATS

Tags: r, matrix, orthogonal

Ok here is an update. You will have the same input matrix as I do.

I start with the following matrix X:

```
X <- matrix(0,10,25)
X[1,6] <- 1
X[2,11] <- 1
X[3,16] <- 1
X[4,21] <- 1
X[5,12] <- 1
X[6,17] <- 1
X[7,22] <- 1
X[8,18] <- 1
X[9,23] <- 1
X[10,21] <- -1.46114
X[10,22] <- 0.005024144
X[10,23] <- 0.005329883
X[10,24] <- 1.050356
X[10,25] <- 0.09473591
```

This matrix is supposed to be transformed into a matrix Y that is `(25x15)`.
Since this one is pretty big I just give u a few values (bottom right should look like this):

```
Y[24,14] = 0.0080693
Y[25,14] = -0.0894663
Y[24,15] = -0.0894663
Y[25,15] = 0.9919307
```

This transformation is described as follows:

**It uses the singular value decomposition taking the columns corresponding to zero singular values.**

I tried to find the solution with `svd()` but didnt succeed. In RATS this exact transformation is managed by the procedure `%perp`. And an Estima guy explained to me, that 
this procedure "uses the singular value decomposition taking the columns corresponding to zero singular values".

Hope that the data provided helps to find the solution.

Martin

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance. What exactly do you mean by "computes the orthogonal matrix to input matrix A"? Does that mean the [QR decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition)?

Comment: http://www.estima.com/newslett/March2006RATSLetter.pdf   Page 4, bottom left...

Comment: There is function `Null` in package MASS.

Comment: @Roland....gonna try that, thanks so far!

Comment: We're getting closer ;) The R function Null() is like the function %Nullspace in RATS (see link above again). The dimensions of the output Matrix do depend on the rank of the input matrix. But %Perp assumes that the input Matrix has full rank. Thats the only thing I have to find a solution for now...

Comment: Well, tried a lot now. Even manipulated the `Null`function within the MASS package. Didnt work. In my example my input matrix is `(10x25)`. The output matrix is supposed to be `(25x15)` (thats what rats computes). But I can just output `(10x10)`matrices in R :/

Comment: Anyone an idea? Or in what *.src file can I find the %perop procedure?

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you want to use the function for. There might be (better) alternatives. In the worst case you can always write a function yourself.

Comment: I want to translate the procedure "shortandlong" from RATS. It applies long and short run restrictions to a VAR estimate. First it computes the vector `r` which is a `(10x25)` and then the `rp` which is supposed to be that orthogonal `(25X15)` one.

Comment: Then it puts together a set of equations based on `rp`, `sigma` and `b`and finds the solution with Newtons method.

Comment: "It uses the singular value decomposition taking the columns corresponding to zero singular values." This is what RATS support told me about the procedure `%perp`. I guess `svd()` might be the right answer?